# Given two matrices A and C (containing $x$) find the value of $x$ knowing that $|A^TC|=20$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given two matrices A and C (containing $x$) find the value of $x$ knowing that $|A^TC|=20$

The two matrices are

$A=\begin{pmatrix}2x&1\\1&4\end{pmatrix}$ and $C=\begin{pmatrix}3&2\\1&2\end{pmatrix}$

How do I find $x$ knowing that $|A^T  C|=20$

I've tried a way and got an answer, but it's not fitting in.

I'll highly appreciate it if you can show me all the steps and the final answer as well.

Comment: For clarification, are you using $|~~|$ to denote determinant or matrix(operator) norm?  Also, please check that the matrices I wrote are indeed the matrices you intended.  It seems odd to refer to $A^T$ when $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: I am using it to denote the determinant

Comment: You say "but it's not fitting in."  What do you mean by that?  Try showing your work and your answer and we can spot a mistake if one exists.  Without showing what you did, I don't know if my answer does exactly what you already thought to do.

Comment: I got 24/32 now that I resolved it. How can I check if this answers works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  Instead of trying to first compute what the matrix $A^T C$ looks like, it is better to begin using the following theorem:

> For square matrices $A$ and $B$ you have:
>   $$\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$$

Also, you have the following:

> For square matrix $A$ you have:
>   $$\det(A)=\det(A^T)$$

Calculate the determinants individually (the one on the left will depend on a variable) and multiply the results.  Given the conditions in the problem, the result will be a linear equation which can be solved using elementary techniques.

---

**Additional hint/reminder:**

The determinant of a $2\times 2$ matrix is given by:

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix} = ad-bc$$

More general formulae for determinants for matrices of this or larger sizes can be found in any textbook.

Given this result and the matrices shown above we have that 
$\det(C) = $

> $\det(C)=3\cdot 2 - 2\cdot 1 = 6-2=4$

Find $\det(A)$ similarly and multiply the results together and finish solving.

Comment: I tried resolving it using this way and I got 24/32. Is that right? How can I check?

Comment: @user276520 that is not the answer I get.  Are you taking the determinants of your $2\times 2$ matrices correctly?  What is the determinant you get for $A$?  For $C$?  Are the listed matrices above the correct matrices for the problem or are there typos/mistakes?

Comment: |A|=8x-1. |C|=4. |A^TxC|=(8x-1)(4)=32x-4. 32x-4=20. x=24/32 @JMoravitz

Comment: @user276520 Ah, I didn't pay close enough attention.  Yes, that is correct then.  It is best to simplify your fractions.  $\frac{24}{32}=\frac{3}{4}$